# Match the field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb sample data result  like this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 3,
        "day" : 24,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    "commodity" : [ 
        {
            "commodityId" : ObjectId("58d434c30da1364f1e2d682d"),
            "commodityStock" : "88889s"
        }
    ],
    "totalStock" : 0,
    "count" : 1.0 }
```

my question is, How can i get the result where month = 3 with $match? 
below is my query:

```js
db.orders.aggregate(
   [
    { $match : {_id.month : 3}},
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$createdAt" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }, year: { $year: "$createdAt" } },
            commodity : {$push : {
                                'commodityId' : "$commodity",
                                'commodityStock' : "$stock",
                            }
                        },
           totalStock: { $sum: "$stock" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: There is no `createdAt` field in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline which incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** so that you can filter the documents in the collection by using a logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [{ "$month": "$createdAt" }, 3]}, 
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {            
            "_id": { 
                "month": { "$month": "$createdAt" }, 
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt" }, 
                "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" } 
            },
            "commodity": {
                "$push": {
                    "commodityId": "$commodity",
                    "commodityStock": "$stock",
                }
            },
            "totalStock": { "$sum": "$stock" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

---

Keep in mind that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** does not use indexes, it performs a collection scan, but if you need to take advantage of indexes use the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline stages as:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "createdAt": 1,
            "month": { "$month": "$createdAt" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt" }, 
            "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" }, 
            "commodity": 1,
            "stock": 1
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "month": 3 } },
    {
        "$group": {            
            "_id": { "month": "$month", "day": "$day", "year": "$year" },
            "commodity": {
                "$push": {
                    "commodityId": "$commodity",
                    "commodityStock": "$stock",
                }
            },
            "totalStock": { "$sum": "$stock" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```